# View all mysql data in InfoWindows gmap

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, gis

I have a problem with the script below, how to display data from mysql into infowindow?

Data shown is all the data in MySQL. Can I use the following script

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM map WHERE id='$_get[id]'");
while($sq=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo " Name = $sq[name]";
echo " Address = $sq[address]";
}
```

to display the map?

This above is my problem script:

```
function ambildatabase(akhir){
if(akhir=="akhir"){
    url = "ambildata.php?akhir=1";
}else{
    url = "ambildata.php?akhir=0";
}
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(msg){
        for(i=0;i<msg.wilayah.petak.length;i++){
            judulx[i] = msg.wilayah.petak[i].judul;
            desx[i] = msg.wilayah.petak[i].deskripsi;
            set_icon(msg.wilayah.petak[i].jenis);

            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(msg.wilayah.petak[i].x),
                parseFloat(msg.wilayah.petak[i].y));
            var tanda = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: point,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
                map: peta,
                icon: gambar_tanda
            });
            setinfo(tanda,i);

        }
    }
});
}
```

This is the place of content:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: "asdasdasd" 


});

function setinfo(petak, nomor){
google.maps.event.addListener(petak, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(peta,petak);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems you need to solve:

1. Your php script is not returning valid json. You should collect all your data in a variable(s) and in the end do something like `echo json_encode($your_data);`
2. There seems to be no relation between the data you are getting from mysql and the variables you are using in javascript: Your javascript variable names suggest a nested structure of arrays / objects where you are just getting `Name` and `Address` from the database. If you want your result to contain stuff like `msg.wilayah.petak[i].deskripsi` you would need to generate the right structure first in php.

And you have an sql injection error, you should switch to PDO (or mysqli) and prepared statements with bound variables.

Comment: thanks for your answers, i just want a show the script--> judulx[i] desx[i] in the infowindows. but i can't.  can you give me the right script. or example. thx.